# Trigger task when battery is about a specific percentage

Tags: windows-phone-8, triggers, batterylevel, background-task

For confidential reasons, I cannot explain all the context of my problem. Through a windows phone app, I would like to let users choose a battery status to trigger a specific task. For example, the user choosed that a task have to be triggered when the battery is about 30% of charge. Users can choose plenty of battery status to trigger a task. These choosed percentages will be inserted in local database. Does somebody knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your case you can use `RemainingChargePercentChanged` Event of `Battery class`. The Event Occurs when the value of RemainingChargePercent decreases by 1%.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Battery _battery = Battery.GetDefault();
    _battery.RemainingChargePercentChanged += _battery_RemainingChargePercentChanged;
}


void _battery_RemainingChargePercentChanged(object sender, object e)
{
    Battery _battery = Battery.GetDefault();
    MessageBox.Show(_battery.RemainingChargePercent.ToString());
}
```

You can have more Reference here [Battery Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207231)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more question, the app will especially work in background. Could I use that method as a trigger ?